# mapping over lists and selecting columns (to create new lists)

Tags: r

I am trying to map over some data and select some columns. I try to run the folling:

```
map(dat$splits, ~ analysis(.x) %>%
      as_tibble(., .name_repair = "universal") %>% 
            map(., ~select(X1, X2, X3, X4, X5, X6, X7, X8, X9)))
```

But get given an error, however I can see the tibbles by using:

```
map(dat$splits, ~ analysis(.x))
```

Which gives:

```
[[1]]
# A tibble: 20 x 17
   date       ID     var1     var2     Y Y_plus_1    X1    X2    X3    X4     X5      X6     X7      X8
   <date>     <chr> <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>
 1 2016-10-21 CAT1   799.  3.01e-3     1        0  4.14    18     0     1 0.0770 4.29e-4  0.652 -0.976 
 2 2016-10-24 CAT1   813.  1.72e-2     1        1  4.14    17     0     1 0.0793 4.24e-4  0.634 -0.861 
 3 2016-10-25 CAT1   808. -6.69e-3     0        1  4.16    16     0     1 0.0804 4.04e-4  0.780 -0.478 
 4 2016-10-26 CAT1   799. -1.06e-2     0        0  4.16    15     0     1 0.0626 4.26e-4  0.378 -0.332 
 5 2016-10-27 CAT1   795. -4.66e-3     0        0  4.16    14     0     1 0.0587 4.42e-4 -0.253 -0.647 
 6 2016-10-28 CAT1   795.  2.52e-5     0        0  4.11    13     0     1 0.0610 4.40e-4 -0.523 -0.753 
 7 2016-10-31 CAT1   785. -1.36e-2     0        0  4.14    12     0     1 0.0704 4.25e-4 -0.125 -0.620 
 8 2016-11-01 CAT1   784. -1.19e-3     1        0  3.98    11     0     1 0.0867 4.17e-4 -0.933 -1.30  
 9 2016-11-02 CAT1   769. -1.90e-2     0        1  6.00    10     0     1 0.0673 4.53e-4 -0.958 -0.793 
10 2016-11-03 CAT1   762. -8.55e-3     0        0  8.42    10     0     1 0.0877 4.29e-4 -1.51  -1.17  
11 2016-11-04 CAT1   762. -1.44e-4     1        0  7.95    10     0     1 0.0924 4.26e-4 -1.67  -1.21  
12 2016-11-07 CAT1   783.  2.69e-2     1        1  7.89    10     0     1 0.0821 4.24e-4 -1.64  -1.06  
13 2016-11-08 CAT1   791.  1.02e-2     1        1  7.64    10     0     1 0.0361 4.51e-4 -0.963  0.0116
14 2016-11-09 CAT1   785. -6.58e-3     1        1  4.51    10     0     1 0.0634 4.87e-4 -0.762  1.15  
15 2016-11-10 CAT1   763. -2.90e-2     0        1  4.53    10     0     1 0.0290 5.26e-4 -1.32   0.560 
16 2016-11-11 CAT1   754. -1.12e-2     0        0  4.40    10     0     1 0.0404 4.94e-4 -1.74   0.142 
17 2016-11-14 CAT1   736. -2.38e-2     0        0  4.19    10     0     1 0.0587 4.93e-4 -2.32  -0.504 
18 2016-11-15 CAT1   758.  3.04e-2     1        0  4.27    10     0     1 0.125  4.17e-4 -2.74  -1.19  
19 2016-11-16 CAT1   764.  7.90e-3     1        1  2.31    29     0     1 0.0637 3.30e-4 -2.16   0.593 
20 2016-11-17 CAT1   771.  8.83e-3     1        1  2.31    28
```

That is I want to map over and select the X1... X8 columns.

Data:

```
dat <- structure(list(splits = list(structure(list(data = structure(list(
    date = structure(c(17095, 17098, 17099, 17100, 17101, 17102, 
    17105, 17106, 17107, 17108, 17109, 17112, 17113, 17114, 17115, 
    17116, 17119, 17120, 17121, 17122, 17123, 17126, 17127, 17128, 
    17130, 17133, 17134, 17135, 17136, 17137, 17140, 17141, 17142, 
    17143, 17144, 17147, 17148, 17149, 17150, 17151, 17154, 17155, 
    17156, 17157, 17158, 17162, 17163, 17164, 17165), class = "Date"), 
    ID = c("CAT1", "CAT1", "CAT1", "CAT1", "CAT1", "CAT1", "CAT1", 
    "CAT1", "CAT1", "CAT1", "CAT1", "CAT1", "CAT1", "CAT1", "CAT1", 
    "CAT1", "CAT1", "CAT1", "CAT1", "CAT1", "CAT1", "CAT1", "CAT1", 
    "CAT1", "CAT1", "CAT1", "CAT1", "CAT1", "CAT1", "CAT1", "CAT1", 
    "CAT1", "CAT1", "CAT1", "CAT1", "CAT1", "CAT1", "CAT1", "CAT1", 
    "CAT1", "CAT1", "CAT1", "CAT1", "CAT1", "CAT1", "CAT1", "CAT1", 
    "CAT1", "CAT1"), var1 = c(799.369995, 813.109985, 807.669983, 
    799.070007, 795.349976, 795.369995, 784.539978, 783.609985, 
    768.700012, 762.130005, 762.02002, 782.52002, 790.51001, 
    785.309998, 762.559998, 754.02002, 736.080017, 758.48999, 
    764.47998, 771.22998, 760.539978, 769.200012, 768.27002, 
    760.98999, 761.679993, 768.23999, 770.840027, 758.039978, 
    747.919983, 750.5, 762.52002, 759.109985, 771.190002, 776.419983, 
    789.289978, 789.27002, 796.099976, 797.070007, 797.849976, 
    790.799988, 794.200012, 796.419983, 794.559998, 791.26001, 
    789.909973, 791.549988, 785.049988, 782.789978, 771.820007
    ), var2 = c(0.00301143592272179, 0.0171885235697395, -0.00669036428079295, 
    -0.0106478836418512, -0.00465545067066953, 0.0000251700516804565, 
    -0.0136163258207899, -0.00118539912060411, -0.0190272881732103, 
    -0.00854690633203736, -0.000144312649125955, 0.0269021803390415, 
    0.0102105886057713, -0.00657804700031572, -0.0289694516279417, 
    -0.0111990899370517, -0.0237924756958046, 0.0304450229355975, 
    0.00789725649510542, 0.0088295314155904, -0.0138609782778413, 
    0.0113866913646978, -0.0012090379426567, -0.00947587412040363, 
    0.00090671757719174, 0.00861253683999563, 0.00338440726054889, 
    -0.016605324777718, -0.0133502127773003, 0.00344958960669994, 
    0.0160160159893405, -0.00447205963195563, 0.0159133949476373, 
    0.00678170228664343, 0.0165760738798502, -0.0000252860172512692, 
    0.00865350998635406, 0.00121847887105075, 0.000978545163097477, 
    -0.00883623264030775, 0.00429947401567232, 0.00279522911918573, 
    -0.00233543235943645, -0.00415322695366804, -0.00170618631415476, 
    0.00207620495506755, -0.00821173659091756, -0.00287881031086645, 
    -0.0140139389980795), Y = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
    1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
    0), Y_plus_1 = c(0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0), X1 = c(4.13858526513854, 
    4.13858526513855, 4.16341131085939, 4.16341131085937, 4.16341131085937, 
    4.11423119297315, 4.13858526513857, 3.97599968560627, 5.99758130881283, 
    8.41953801047614, 7.95231443679086, 7.88558780320248, 7.6408950559188, 
    4.51370117323327, 4.52868963859669, 4.39998987943623, 4.18852747359839, 
    4.27042958796773, 2.30720560360487, 2.3083029424251, 2.3083029424251, 
    2.30720560360488, 2.30720560360486, 2.33467572807035, 2.33467572807036, 
    2.33467572807036, 2.30720560360486, 2.33467572807035, 2.31545097851707, 
    2.3399413414153, 2.40685890963718, 2.40309440701756, 2.33633188340289, 
    2.3363318834029, 2.23996107961566, 2.23996107961567, 2.23996107961566, 
    3.14644299189703, 3.1910343925295, 3.4393907031427, 3.30413087760388, 
    3.33080017630688, 2.63827508869038, 2.99443088216722, 2.99443088216723, 
    2.99443088216722, 2.99443088216722, 3.14542139469794, 3.14542139469794
    ), X2 = c(18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
    10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 29, 28, 27, 26, 25, 24, 23, 22, 21, 
    20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
    87, 86, 85, 84, 83, 82, 81), X3 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0), X4 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), X5 = c(0.0769944316144198, 
    0.0793311568823971, 0.0803743155230278, 0.0625789438826206, 
    0.0586506192715035, 0.0610303101083243, 0.0703939970975855, 
    0.0867098273608016, 0.0673120522212106, 0.0877296725069155, 
    0.0923742675361241, 0.0821050363880187, 0.0360531976099817, 
    0.063410467337928, 0.0289807505667197, 0.0403890038946993, 
    0.0587200889534704, 0.124855015077667, 0.0636602113103218, 
    0.0748772236055617, 0.0828248414842617, 0.0588561607897347, 
    0.0437146614571738, 0.0399432627968126, 0.0535895503558405, 
    0.0538598239712004, 0.0600971764378981, 0.0543532803438423, 
    0.0412119504402689, 0.0445593481900316, 0.0471324573693227, 
    0.0366910541674913, 0.0412784111781792, 0.0338162772274317, 
    0.0391189676384125, 0.051151724195942, 0.0442197922283997, 
    0.0458769828703159, 0.0392536462039503, 0.0397989336000519, 
    0.0293505218180493, 0.0229058449521028, 0.0154019371887762, 
    0.0102366640366435, 0.00783792657548366, 0.014037818210456, 
    0.00900392496961011, 0.0148108452415051, 0.0159871581537364
    ), X6 = c(0.000428660536007568, 0.000424348382531349, 0.000403672086504106, 
    0.000425772306880377, 0.000441567036819891, 0.000440420473928468, 
    0.000424616565866307, 0.000417156794102717, 0.000453102696396517, 
    0.000429420158272163, 0.000426339236438714, 0.000424204011080916, 
    0.000450812884669126, 0.00048728803860348, 0.000526461561504051, 
    0.000494106517096305, 0.000493488610269819, 0.00041740609044358, 
    0.000329604373072286, 0.000321981688032803, 0.000313820182149535, 
    0.000324018084037671, 0.000321928021838835, 0.000325886279909115, 
    0.000324905583026473, 0.000323263064904554, 0.000315582726878559, 
    0.00033115144688, 0.000326176783596685, 0.000320421043513733, 
    0.000317459171547033, 0.000306378296724892, 0.000304230982248009, 
    0.00031578316067723, 0.000315783239223671, 0.000308443856342272, 
    0.000302387474982801, 0.000302702247056619, 0.000300580888361005, 
    0.000298662388842681, 0.000295031270763261, 0.000300955138678924, 
    0.000308009865186193, 0.00031004060452567, 0.000308580481883199, 
    0.000309081734643359, 0.000309347430761987, 0.00031610525741575, 
    0.000316030523318374), X7 = c(0.652246323794644, 0.633658121909502, 
    0.779640005424855, 0.37849713571782, -0.25338461752528, -0.522937755983531, 
    -0.124971717359712, -0.93339126000489, -0.957987757878853, 
    -1.50800507959919, -1.67334654587184, -1.6438607078889, -0.962881285608565, 
    -0.761952591493898, -1.31627449065341, -1.73806924167703, 
    -2.31894300820554, -2.73548173635386, -2.16326733735933, 
    -2.18976199245069, -1.70174528306041, -2.05934220840334, 
    -1.83997395786783, -1.66507504806585, -1.90235222119862, 
    -1.84142082212644, -1.77786289146221, -1.23082082088862, 
    -1.53821065097434, -1.56812844617651, -1.59984630224514, 
    -1.15906488048868, -1.18713323505712, -0.57100200805735, 
    -0.228511848060405, 0.253315947225092, 0.0532312338057499, 
    0.223428854601438, -0.00144862031236322, -0.0398092612664749, 
    -0.0588761129681466, -0.0771471433941018, 0.117493259867833, 
    0.459197464971977, 0.292335416896516, 0.114242276938583, 
    0.202233666501737, 0.331679162319782, 0.175470525372577), 
    X8 = c(-0.975973892452776, -0.861258722930479, -0.477565916680931, 
    -0.33185021650311, -0.647129621511124, -0.752564004048953, 
    -0.620377457915967, -1.30234931058582, -0.793283548875438, 
    -1.16602371553076, -1.20919980603818, -1.06429334017641, 
    0.0115994967476536, 1.15288649261686, 0.559547871095353, 
    0.142148842103466, -0.504045772338972, -1.18889934824633, 
    0.593184249578906, 0.999978721521271, 1.3874173248314, 0.798117587221041, 
    0.799993914873595, 0.748516271275043, 0.617354487136954, 
    0.66965220108721, 0.886228797393692, 1.10466660545966, 0.37553937583687, 
    0.113225726134138, 0.35930466268218, 0.588184742745078, 0.536929080120224, 
    0.875533406569582, 1.29869394121533, 1.3954069386108, 1.2896602501424, 
    1.28952719595234, 1.04620293691641, 1.04835604946992, 0.944659231862545, 
    0.658278997146449, 0.530493113505759, 0.386873773618166, 
    0.412971784704427, 0.116661980563476, 0.274658721324867, 
    -0.231454627137936, -0.0490920485204462), X9 = c(-0.0145637619761308, 
    -0.0147930666936059, -0.0147662947883565, -0.0325177535962596, 
    -0.0128572105783758, -0.0126204141222343, -0.0193506283734377, 
    -0.0204879399440294, -0.015817519858536, -0.0171950326442131, 
    -0.0146419066547099, -0.0104033279055883, -0.00702994914474458, 
    0.012163515055523, 0.0311052843018782, 0.0466972362285693, 
    0.0638538376999092, 0.0587189119891982, -0.0382761719744182, 
    0.017369814913167, 0.00894072522957917, 0.0159165549773805, 
    -0.00278974160229076, 0.00087423648615031, -0.000799924570855513, 
    -0.00720654828839435, 0.00144205696290743, -0.00744120420924264, 
    -0.00623238593684327, 0.0140296542021987, 0.0078581351311665, 
    0.0194264610155223, 0.0214019946797077, 0.0135050903487779, 
    0.0136275994696147, 0.0191532733906993, 0.0145192162284441, 
    0.0180836191687308, 0.0211148970828572, 0.0228082176297255, 
    0.0282007760760499, 0.0246107996585935, 0.0169675399817873, 
    0.0207974225382235, 0.0246684486060467, 0.0216975706632474, 
    0.0291883466992148, 0.0253376536386199, 0.0262304363854249
    ), X10 = c(0.225525775667678, 0.218320938251066, 0.205736199627003, 
    0.18430441198689, 0.171653942908123, 0.169720213220954, 0.169160112065287, 
    0.162051896119269, 0.158642308835919, 0.163696353319601, 
    0.162160340961121, 0.160663336867733, 0.116728767616044, 
    0.0744707092081847, 0.0816373143043771, 0.120472162777503, 
    0.120923040165681, 0.10545848677116, 0.172548378854213, 0.184998553367414, 
    0.181410472295269, 0.248454355918383, 0.218320516349615, 
    0.216853385184294, 0.180488106442423, 0.177799948562715, 
    0.186118707334448, 0.177473777344988, 0.161807804965392, 
    0.167723342514708, 0.158568160654393, 0.16773089626074, 0.16307716529608, 
    0.162099891399657, 0.15812964617053, 0.149690169923917, 0.164750142363451, 
    0.163460075128328, 0.155183021202297, 0.14616757689419, 0.154376710865108, 
    0.147389439599357, 0.183009449087266, 0.175519602867033, 
    0.177732643891337, 0.17814584046646, 0.175149718955584, 0.176134687816332, 
    0.175399285149764), X11 = c(0.510204081632653, 0.520408163265306, 
    0.520408163265306, 0.530612244897959, 0.530612244897959, 
    0.520408163265306, 0.520408163265306, 0.520408163265306, 
    0.530612244897959, 0.520408163265306, 0.530612244897959, 
    0.530612244897959, 0.540816326530612, 0.530612244897959, 
    0.520408163265306, 0.530612244897959, 0.530612244897959, 
    0.530612244897959, 0.536082474226804, 0.536082474226804, 
    0.536082474226804, 0.530612244897959, 0.525773195876289, 
    0.536082474226804, 0.510204081632653, 0.520408163265306, 
    0.520408163265306, 0.530612244897959, 0.530612244897959, 
    0.520408163265306, 0.510204081632653, 0.510204081632653, 
    0.510204081632653, 0.510204081632653, 0.510204081632653, 
    0.5, 0.5, 0.489795918367347, 0.489795918367347, 0.489795918367347, 
    0.5, 0.5, 0.510204081632653, 0.5, 0.5, 0.510204081632653, 
    0.510204081632653, 0.520408163265306, 0.520408163265306)), row.names = c(NA, 
-49L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), in_id = 1:20, 
    out_id = 21L, id = structure(list(id = "Slice01"), row.names = c(NA, 
    -1L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))), class = c("rsplit", 
"rof_split")), structure(list(data = structure(list(date = structure(c(17095, 
17098, 17099, 17100, 17101, 17102, 17105, 17106, 17107, 17108, 
17109, 17112, 17113, 17114, 17115, 17116, 17119, 17120, 17121, 
17122, 17123, 17126, 17127, 17128, 17130, 17133, 17134, 17135, 
17136, 17137, 17140, 17141, 17142, 17143, 17144, 17147, 17148, 
17149, 17150, 17151, 17154, 17155, 17156, 17157, 17158, 17162, 
17163, 17164, 17165), class = "Date"), ID = c("CAT1", "CAT1", 
"CAT1", "CAT1", "CAT1", "CAT1", "CAT1", "CAT1", "CAT1", "CAT1", 
"CAT1", "CAT1", "CAT1", "CAT1", "CAT1", "CAT1", "CAT1", "CAT1", 
"CAT1", "CAT1", "CAT1", "CAT1", "CAT1", "CAT1", "CAT1", "CAT1", 
"CAT1", "CAT1", "CAT1", "CAT1", "CAT1", "CAT1", "CAT1", "CAT1", 
"CAT1", "CAT1", "CAT1", "CAT1", "CAT1", "CAT1", "CAT1", "CAT1", 
"CAT1", "CAT1", "CAT1", "CAT1", "CAT1", "CAT1", "CAT1"), var1 = c(799.369995, 
813.109985, 807.669983, 799.070007, 795.349976, 795.369995, 784.539978, 
783.609985, 768.700012, 762.130005, 762.02002, 782.52002, 790.51001, 
785.309998, 762.559998, 754.02002, 736.080017, 758.48999, 764.47998, 
771.22998, 760.539978, 769.200012, 768.27002, 760.98999, 761.679993, 
768.23999, 770.840027, 758.039978, 747.919983, 750.5, 762.52002, 
759.109985, 771.190002, 776.419983, 789.289978, 789.27002, 796.099976, 
797.070007, 797.849976, 790.799988, 794.200012, 796.419983, 794.559998, 
791.26001, 789.909973, 791.549988, 785.049988, 782.789978, 771.820007
), var2 = c(0.00301143592272179, 0.0171885235697395, -0.00669036428079295, 
-0.0106478836418512, -0.00465545067066953, 0.0000251700516804565, 
-0.0136163258207899, -0.00118539912060411, -0.0190272881732103, 
-0.00854690633203736, -0.000144312649125955, 0.0269021803390415, 
0.0102105886057713, -0.00657804700031572, -0.0289694516279417, 
-0.0111990899370517, -0.0237924756958046, 0.0304450229355975, 
0.00789725649510542, 0.0088295314155904, -0.0138609782778413, 
0.0113866913646978, -0.0012090379426567, -0.00947587412040363, 
0.00090671757719174, 0.00861253683999563, 0.00338440726054889, 
-0.016605324777718, -0.0133502127773003, 0.00344958960669994, 
0.0160160159893405, -0.00447205963195563, 0.0159133949476373, 
0.00678170228664343, 0.0165760738798502, -0.0000252860172512692, 
0.00865350998635406, 0.00121847887105075, 0.000978545163097477, 
-0.00883623264030775, 0.00429947401567232, 0.00279522911918573, 
-0.00233543235943645, -0.00415322695366804, -0.00170618631415476, 
0.00207620495506755, -0.00821173659091756, -0.00287881031086645, 
-0.0140139389980795), Y = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0), Y_plus_1 = c(0, 
1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0), X1 = c(4.13858526513854, 4.13858526513855, 
4.16341131085939, 4.16341131085937, 4.16341131085937, 4.11423119297315, 
4.13858526513857, 3.97599968560627, 5.99758130881283, 8.41953801047614, 
7.95231443679086, 7.88558780320248, 7.6408950559188, 4.51370117323327, 
4.52868963859669, 4.39998987943623, 4.18852747359839, 4.27042958796773, 
2.30720560360487, 2.3083029424251, 2.3083029424251, 2.30720560360488, 
2.30720560360486, 2.33467572807035, 2.33467572807036, 2.33467572807036, 
2.30720560360486, 2.33467572807035, 2.31545097851707, 2.3399413414153, 
2.40685890963718, 2.40309440701756, 2.33633188340289, 2.3363318834029, 
2.23996107961566, 2.23996107961567, 2.23996107961566, 3.14644299189703, 
3.1910343925295, 3.4393907031427, 3.30413087760388, 3.33080017630688, 
2.63827508869038, 2.99443088216722, 2.99443088216723, 2.99443088216722, 
2.99443088216722, 3.14542139469794, 3.14542139469794), X2 = c(18, 
17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
10, 29, 28, 27, 26, 25, 24, 23, 22, 21, 20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 
14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 87, 86, 85, 84, 83, 82, 81
), X3 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), X4 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1
), X5 = c(0.0769944316144198, 0.0793311568823971, 0.0803743155230278, 
0.0625789438826206, 0.0586506192715035, 0.0610303101083243, 0.0703939970975855, 
0.0867098273608016, 0.0673120522212106, 0.0877296725069155, 0.0923742675361241, 
0.0821050363880187, 0.0360531976099817, 0.063410467337928, 0.0289807505667197, 
0.0403890038946993, 0.0587200889534704, 0.124855015077667, 0.0636602113103218, 
0.0748772236055617, 0.0828248414842617, 0.0588561607897347, 0.0437146614571738, 
0.0399432627968126, 0.0535895503558405, 0.0538598239712004, 0.0600971764378981, 
0.0543532803438423, 0.0412119504402689, 0.0445593481900316, 0.0471324573693227, 
0.0366910541674913, 0.0412784111781792, 0.0338162772274317, 0.0391189676384125, 
0.051151724195942, 0.0442197922283997, 0.0458769828703159, 0.0392536462039503, 
0.0397989336000519, 0.0293505218180493, 0.0229058449521028, 0.0154019371887762, 
0.0102366640366435, 0.00783792657548366, 0.014037818210456, 0.00900392496961011, 
0.0148108452415051, 0.0159871581537364), X6 = c(0.000428660536007568, 
0.000424348382531349, 0.000403672086504106, 0.000425772306880377, 
0.000441567036819891, 0.000440420473928468, 0.000424616565866307, 
0.000417156794102717, 0.000453102696396517, 0.000429420158272163, 
0.000426339236438714, 0.000424204011080916, 0.000450812884669126, 
0.00048728803860348, 0.000526461561504051, 0.000494106517096305, 
0.000493488610269819, 0.00041740609044358, 0.000329604373072286, 
0.000321981688032803, 0.000313820182149535, 0.000324018084037671, 
0.000321928021838835, 0.000325886279909115, 0.000324905583026473, 
0.000323263064904554, 0.000315582726878559, 0.00033115144688, 
0.000326176783596685, 0.000320421043513733, 0.000317459171547033, 
0.000306378296724892, 0.000304230982248009, 0.00031578316067723, 
0.000315783239223671, 0.000308443856342272, 0.000302387474982801, 
0.000302702247056619, 0.000300580888361005, 0.000298662388842681, 
0.000295031270763261, 0.000300955138678924, 0.000308009865186193, 
0.00031004060452567, 0.000308580481883199, 0.000309081734643359, 
0.000309347430761987, 0.00031610525741575, 0.000316030523318374
), X7 = c(0.652246323794644, 0.633658121909502, 0.779640005424855, 
0.37849713571782, -0.25338461752528, -0.522937755983531, -0.124971717359712, 
-0.93339126000489, -0.957987757878853, -1.50800507959919, -1.67334654587184, 
-1.6438607078889, -0.962881285608565, -0.761952591493898, -1.31627449065341, 
-1.73806924167703, -2.31894300820554, -2.73548173635386, -2.16326733735933, 
-2.18976199245069, -1.70174528306041, -2.05934220840334, -1.83997395786783, 
-1.66507504806585, -1.90235222119862, -1.84142082212644, -1.77786289146221, 
-1.23082082088862, -1.53821065097434, -1.56812844617651, -1.59984630224514, 
-1.15906488048868, -1.18713323505712, -0.57100200805735, -0.228511848060405, 
0.253315947225092, 0.0532312338057499, 0.223428854601438, -0.00144862031236322, 
-0.0398092612664749, -0.0588761129681466, -0.0771471433941018, 
0.117493259867833, 0.459197464971977, 0.292335416896516, 0.114242276938583, 
0.202233666501737, 0.331679162319782, 0.175470525372577), X8 = c(-0.975973892452776, 
-0.861258722930479, -0.477565916680931, -0.33185021650311, -0.647129621511124, 
-0.752564004048953, -0.620377457915967, -1.30234931058582, -0.793283548875438, 
-1.16602371553076, -1.20919980603818, -1.06429334017641, 0.0115994967476536, 
1.15288649261686, 0.559547871095353, 0.142148842103466, -0.504045772338972, 
-1.18889934824633, 0.593184249578906, 0.999978721521271, 1.3874173248314, 
0.798117587221041, 0.799993914873595, 0.748516271275043, 0.617354487136954, 
0.66965220108721, 0.886228797393692, 1.10466660545966, 0.37553937583687, 
0.113225726134138, 0.35930466268218, 0.588184742745078, 0.536929080120224, 
0.875533406569582, 1.29869394121533, 1.3954069386108, 1.2896602501424, 
1.28952719595234, 1.04620293691641, 1.04835604946992, 0.944659231862545, 
0.658278997146449, 0.530493113505759, 0.386873773618166, 0.412971784704427, 
0.116661980563476, 0.274658721324867, -0.231454627137936, -0.0490920485204462
), X9 = c(-0.0145637619761308, -0.0147930666936059, -0.0147662947883565, 
-0.0325177535962596, -0.0128572105783758, -0.0126204141222343, 
-0.0193506283734377, -0.0204879399440294, -0.015817519858536, 
-0.0171950326442131, -0.0146419066547099, -0.0104033279055883, 
-0.00702994914474458, 0.012163515055523, 0.0311052843018782, 
0.0466972362285693, 0.0638538376999092, 0.0587189119891982, -0.0382761719744182, 
0.017369814913167, 0.00894072522957917, 0.0159165549773805, -0.00278974160229076, 
0.00087423648615031, -0.000799924570855513, -0.00720654828839435, 
0.00144205696290743, -0.00744120420924264, -0.00623238593684327, 
0.0140296542021987, 0.0078581351311665, 0.0194264610155223, 0.0214019946797077, 
0.0135050903487779, 0.0136275994696147, 0.0191532733906993, 0.0145192162284441, 
0.0180836191687308, 0.0211148970828572, 0.0228082176297255, 0.0282007760760499, 
0.0246107996585935, 0.0169675399817873, 0.0207974225382235, 0.0246684486060467, 
0.0216975706632474, 0.0291883466992148, 0.0253376536386199, 0.0262304363854249
), X10 = c(0.225525775667678, 0.218320938251066, 0.205736199627003, 
0.18430441198689, 0.171653942908123, 0.169720213220954, 0.169160112065287, 
0.162051896119269, 0.158642308835919, 0.163696353319601, 0.162160340961121, 
0.160663336867733, 0.116728767616044, 0.0744707092081847, 0.0816373143043771, 
0.120472162777503, 0.120923040165681, 0.10545848677116, 0.172548378854213, 
0.184998553367414, 0.181410472295269, 0.248454355918383, 0.218320516349615, 
0.216853385184294, 0.180488106442423, 0.177799948562715, 0.186118707334448, 
0.177473777344988, 0.161807804965392, 0.167723342514708, 0.158568160654393, 
0.16773089626074, 0.16307716529608, 0.162099891399657, 0.15812964617053, 
0.149690169923917, 0.164750142363451, 0.163460075128328, 0.155183021202297, 
0.14616757689419, 0.154376710865108, 0.147389439599357, 0.183009449087266, 
0.175519602867033, 0.177732643891337, 0.17814584046646, 0.175149718955584, 
0.176134687816332, 0.175399285149764), X11 = c(0.510204081632653, 
0.520408163265306, 0.520408163265306, 0.530612244897959, 0.530612244897959, 
0.520408163265306, 0.520408163265306, 0.520408163265306, 0.530612244897959, 
0.520408163265306, 0.530612244897959, 0.530612244897959, 0.540816326530612, 
0.530612244897959, 0.520408163265306, 0.530612244897959, 0.530612244897959, 
0.530612244897959, 0.536082474226804, 0.536082474226804, 0.536082474226804, 
0.530612244897959, 0.525773195876289, 0.536082474226804, 0.510204081632653, 
0.520408163265306, 0.520408163265306, 0.530612244897959, 0.530612244897959, 
0.520408163265306, 0.510204081632653, 0.510204081632653, 0.510204081632653, 
0.510204081632653, 0.510204081632653, 0.5, 0.5, 0.489795918367347, 
0.489795918367347, 0.489795918367347, 0.5, 0.5, 0.510204081632653, 
0.5, 0.5, 0.510204081632653, 0.510204081632653, 0.520408163265306, 
0.520408163265306)), row.names = c(NA, -49L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame")), in_id = 2:21, out_id = 22L, id = structure(list(
    id = "Slice02"), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))), class = c("rsplit", "rof_split"))), id = c("Slice01", 
"Slice02")), row.names = 1:2, class = c("rset", "tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), initial = 20, assess = 1, cumulative = FALSE, skip = 0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't need the `.` and `map`.  After the `select`, it can be converted to `list` with `as.list` (if it is required), otherwise, just keep it as the `tibble`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
map(dat$splits, ~ analysis(.x) %>%
  as_tibble(., .name_repair = "universal") %>%
          select(X1:X9) %>%
          as.list)
```